# Eclipse build order of maven project is inconsistent

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-neon, eclipse-oxygen

I have two local repos of the same project, two different workspaces one for eclipse neon and one for eclipse oxygen. Both are using the embedded version of maven.

I start by:

1. Unchecking build automatically
2. Import maven projects into my workspace
3. Maven update, force update of snapshots/releases is checked, update project configuration from pom.xml is checked, refresh workspace resources from local filesystem is checked, and clean projects is checked.
4. Check build automatically

This works fine in Neon and doesn't work in Oxygen.

Oxygen gives me "cannot be resolved to a type" errors.

If I go to

> Window/Preferences/General/Workspace/Build Order

the orders are different between the two IDE's.

I've also tried `mvn eclipse:clean` and `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and the build order is still incorrect.

I've also tried removing the projects, doing an eclipse clean, delete the .classpath .project .factorypath files, delete the .settings folders, then same 4 steps I started with. I still get the same errors.

If I change the Oxygen build order to match Neon, do another maven update, it builds fine.

My question, is there something else I can try to make eclipse re-evaluate the build order? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: First do not use `maven-eclipse-plugin` cause it's longer time retired. Better use the import from m2e in Eclipse. Furthermore check the build first on plain command line if it works their...

Comment: Yea, I didn't think mvn eclipse weren't needed.

Comment: Running from the command line works. Running a maven install from eclipse also works. This seems to just be an eclipse issue.

Comment: I filed a bug on m2e since the issue is easily reproducible in Oxygen but doesn't happen in Neon indeed: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=535973

if anyone finds a workaround or solution, please let me know. Looks like I'll have to fallback to Neon for now.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is a bug in Eclipse Oxygen / m2e 1.8.3. I didn't find a workaround for Oxygen but the it seems like no longed exists in `eclipse-SDK-4.8RC4a`. If this is an option for you to use Photon, try it out.

Comment: Photon has the same issue as Oxygen.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my pom resolved the issue.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <versionRange>[1.7,)</versionRange>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <action>
                        <execute/>
                    </action>
                </pluginExecution>
            </pluginExecutions>
        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```